# Curly Brace expected where it shouldn't be expected

Tags: c#, oop

I'm learning c# (and OOP with it) and I'm running the following in Visual Studio, and it keeps popping up with an error that it wants a curly brace `}` where I have written *HERE*. I can't figure out for the life of me why it wants that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace MyFirstProject.day1.examples
{
    class Class
    {
        public double salary;
        public double bonus;

        public void CalculateTotalPay(){
            //HERE
            public double totalpay = salary + bonus;
            Console.WriteLine("TP: " + totalpay);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have just this class in your project or do you have another main method that instantiates this?

Comment: I have put your code in  VS project and it seems fine. Perhaps you are missing a brace from your namespace?

Comment: Do you have any namespace ? your code gets compile for me.

Comment: use [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) to see if you can re-create the issue then post the link to the program that generates the compiler error.

Comment: I updated with the whole file. I'm glad it's not just me doing something dumb.

Comment: is "Class" a reserved word... why not try to use "myClass"

Comment: @logixologist, no it is not.

Comment: Just tried copying it over to another file with the class name "Exampleif", same error.

Comment: Removing the `public` in CalculateTotalPay fixes it, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `public` from the line `public double totalpay = salary + bonus;`, fixed it. I believe the problem was that either since the function was public it was redundant, or since `totalpay` was in the function it couldn't be declared public.

Comment: "or since totalpay was in the function it couldn't be declared public" - that's the actual reason, just FYI. Access modifiers (like public, private, etc) can only be used on members and types - variables declared inside a function are temporary locals that don't exist outside the scope of the function therefore an access modifier on them isn't possible.

Comment: The C# language definition prohibits access modifiers on local variables as it doesn't make sense to have them.

Comment: @Samuel does this mean that I can only return a single value from a function?

Comment: @JamesG Yes, you can return only a single object, but that object can be a list, an array etc